# Call method in same class

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and I was wondering the following, can I call a method in the same class such as:

```
class myClass
    $myVar = inClass

    def inClass
        @value = (gets data from db)
    end
end
```

If there is a way to do this, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below

```
class MyClass

    def in_class
        @value = (gets data from db)
    end
    def call_inclass
        $my_var = in_class # don't use global variable.
    end

end
```

Create a new instance method `call_inclass` and call the required class `in_class` from there. Your one will not work, as `in_class` is an instance method, and within `class.. end` body `self` is set to that class. Thus `$myVar = in_class` will simply thorw an error as **no method error**. Because `$myVar = in_class` it will be interpreted implicitly as `$myVar = self.in_class`, where `self` is `MyClass`. `in_class` is not a method of `MyClass`, rather an instance method of instances of `MyClass`.

Thus wrapped the method call to `in_class` inside another *instance method*, like here `call_inclass`.

Another way is make `in_class` as a singleton method of `MyClass`. Then it will work.

```
class MyClass
    # again don't use global variable, rather use 
    # class instance variable, @my_var
    $my_var = in_class 

    def self.in_class
        @value = (gets data from db)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried both of the examples you gave me, but none of them seem to be working, they are both giving me a "nil" value even after doing this "@value = 2".  I need a global variable to use in all the view pages.